# Sistema de routing ignorando subpastas

Tags: php, routing

Estou usando o sistema de routing [AltoRouter](https://github.com/dannyvankooten/AltoRouter/), e seu uso é bem simples, uso dessa forma:

****    ESTE É O INDEX.PHP *****

```
/*Incluo o arquivo do AltoRouter*/
include ('application/router.php');

$router = new AltoRouter();
$router -> setBasePath('/mvc/'); ** aqui é o diretório base **

$router -> map('GET', 'noticia', 'noticia#index', 'noticia');

$match = $router -> match();

**Aqui a estrutura da chamada controlller#action no padrão MVC**

if ($match === false) {

header('Location: /mvc/error');

} else {

list($controller, $action) = explode('#', $match['target']);

if (is_callable(array($controller, $action))) {
    $obj = new $controller;
    call_user_func_array(array($obj, $action), $match['params']);
} else {

    exit('O Controller não pôde ser chamado');

}
}
```

o Arquivo .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

O problema é que ao chamar uma view pela classe **VIEW** (onde tem a chamada de dos arquivos frontEnd)... o diretório da parte frontEnd (css, js e imagens) não é reconhecido, o sistema pensa que é um controller, exemplo:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="public/main.css">
```

A página não consegue localizar o arquivo/diretório (public/main.css) e é redirecionada para a página de erro como foi definido no código acima.

Não entendo muito de expressões regulares, mas acho que seja isso, como posso resolver?

Answer (score 1):

No arquivo .htacess, adicione o seguinte

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

Esse código diz que deve ignorar a regra de reescrita caso encontre um diretório físico válido.

Outro ponto é o carregamento de css, js e outros no HTML, inclusive para imagens.

Para garantir a integridade do caminho, defina a base das URLs com a tag `<base>`

Exemplo: `<base href="http://endereço.base.do.site/" target="_blank">`

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp

Caso não queira usar a tag `<base>`, especifique caminhos absolutos ou paths relativos mais concisos.